# Need help with a function

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function that will handle focus for multiple forms. I'm certainly doing something wrong here because it isn't working as expected. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
<a href="#" onclick="x('a','b','')">test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function x(xform, xbox, xval) {
  document.xform.xbox.focus();
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" />
```

Comment: I just tried that but still nothing. Good catch though!

Comment: Where is the `<form>`? What do you mean by `.focus('c')`?

Comment: Kenny, the `focus('c')` is a typo. I had alert in there and then tried focus. I'll edit my question. The form is below my input and is named `a`

Comment: The input must be *in* the form, otherwise it does not work in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the third value (focus does not take any parameter), but it should look like this:

```
document[xform][xbox].focus();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AeWpU/)

Explanation: `document.xform` will access the `xform` property of `document`. But `document[xform]` will access the property taken from the value of `xform`.

Comment: Felix, I'm still having a problem with passing in a value. Is there something special I must do?

Comment: @jim: I don't know what you mean, do you want to *set* a value for the input field?

Comment: Yes, exactly then focus it after the value has been set.

Comment: I thought I could could just follow the focus example but it doesn't work.

Comment: @jim: It depends what kind of form elements you are dealing with. For an `input` element, you do `element.value = newValue`, so you could do `document[xform][xbox].value = xval`

Comment: Thanks Felix. That also worked. Man it must be nice to know JS inside and out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as Felix has...however IDs should be unique in a page, so just this would work:

```
function x(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

Then in your code use the `id` that your `<input>` already has:

```
<a href="#" onclick="x('b')">test</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick. I will make the adjustments and this is also good to know.